# geth warning Stats login failed

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

Hi I am getting an warning in the geth console and not able to communicate with geth from the dapp also.
Here is the warning

> WARN [08-22|13:22:59] Stats login failed           err=unauthorized

What is this warning?? I am using geth with rinkeby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked [ethereum source file](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/ethstats/ethstats.go#L228), if request to authorize the client at the remote server failed, this warning message will be printed, and then sleep 10 seconds to retry. Maybe your network is bad or node server is down. Waiting some time to try it.

Hope it helps~

Comment: Yes you were correct I got this sorted out by giving                                        --ethstats='yournode:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io'

Comment: getting same error even with --ethstats='yournode:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io' – Jazz Aug 22 at 14:15

Comment: Yep, the same error with `ethstats` provided.

Answer (score 7):

I had same error on rinkeby, while starting geth with option:

```
--ethstats='yournode:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io'
```

After changing "yournode" to some unique name the problem was solved.

```
--ethstats='&lt;some_unique_name&gt;:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io'
```